# Java SwingWorker process(chunks) always 0

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to get the hang of the SwingWorker class but I am getting an unexpected behaviour I can not solve.

In my background() method, I am publishing an increasing counter which should be logged as the progress into console.

Somehow the chunks.getSize()-1 always print out 0 instead of the incremented counter variable I am providing using publish(counter). What am I doing wrong here?

```
 SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker<Boolean, Integer>() {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
            int counter = 0;
            for (TickerStatistics ticker : tickers) {
                candleData.put(ticker.getSymbol(), rc.getCandlestickBars(ticker.getSymbol(), interval));
                counter++;
                publish(counter);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            System.out.println(candleData);
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
            System.out.println(chunks.size() - 1 + " / " + tickers.size());
        }
    };
```

Comment: There is no guarantee on what the size of the List parameter is in the process method, and I would not base program logic on this. Instead, better to use the data held by the each chunk instead.

Comment: I am afraid I cant follow your advice.

Comment: Try `chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1)` rather than just `chunks.size() - 1`

Comment: I'm concerned that you are not publishing `TickerStatistics`.  There are thread visibility issues with variables when switching threads, that's the point of calling `publish()` and not just using a field directly.  Is that class thread safe?

Comment: I am not sure if its threadsafe to be honest. There are multiple Objects of the Class that is using a their own swing workers. The data isnt shared between classes.

Comment: I have the impression that you are only reading properties of the `TickerStatistics` objects which wouldn’t be a problem. The real problem is the `candleData.put(…)` call which obviously is meant to *modify* a data structure (a `Map` perhaps). This will definitely require the map to be thread safe. The correct way would be to drop the counter and use something like `publish(Map.entry( ticker.getSymbol(), rc.getCandlestickBars(ticker.getSymbol(), interval)));` within `doInBackground()` and `process(List<Map.Entry<…,…>> chunks) { for(var e: chunks) candleData.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()); }`